# Perfect group of order 190080

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

I need to know some properties of the perfect group of order $190080$
which is the Schur cover of the Mathieu group ${\rm M}_{12}$, but
when using `PerfectGroup(190080),` [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org) runs so slowly.
Is there any other method in GAP for getting this group?

Answer (score 12):

Just write

```
gap> G := PerfectGroup(IsPermGroup,190080);
M12 2^1
```

in order to get the desired group as a permutation group:

```
gap> GeneratorsOfGroup(G);
[ (3,6)(7,10)(9,12)(13,16)(15,18)(19,22)(20,23)(21,24),
  (1,2,3)(4,5,7)(6,8,9)(10,11,13)(12,14,15)(16,17,19)(18,20,21)(22,24,23),
  (1,4)(2,5)(3,7)(6,10)(8,11)(9,13)(12,16)(14,17)(15,19)(18,22)(20,24)(21,23)
 ]
```

Now computations should be fast.
(If you omit the first argument, you get the group as a finitely presented group, and computations with such groups are inefficient for the obvious reasons.)

Comment: One more problem. How I can find the representation of a finite group as a permutation group, because by order GeneratorsOfGroup, generators obtained by a and b ....

Comment: @Sara: You can obtain a faithful permutation representation of a finite group $G$ by `IsomorphismPermGroup(`$G$`)`, and the isomorphic permutation group is `Image(IsomorphismPermGroup(`$G$`))`.

Comment: @Sara It may be worth pointing out that `IsomorphismPermGroup` is not necessarily of smallest degree.  To get a smaller degree permutation representation of a permutation group, use `SmallerDegreePermutationRepresentation` to get a faithful representation of (potentially) smaller degree.  Take the `Image` as before to get the actual permutation group.  This still doesn't guarantee the smallest possible degree representation, but computations tend to be faster in smaller degree so it is helpful to reduce the degree like this.